# export объекта из файла с чистым js в App.js react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть файл first.js на чистом js, который возвращает объект, например, data. Как я могу использовать его в App.js на react не переписывая first.js под react? Например, first.js:

```
var first = (obj) => {
var data = {};
data.first = obj.foo;
data.second = obj.bar;
return data;
};
first ({"foo": 1, "bar": 2});
export default data;
```

А App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from "first.js"
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
<h1>{data.first}</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экспортируете, как обычно это делаете в `React`, только вместо компонента, ваш объект

*first.js*

```
export default {
   prop: 1,
   prop2: 2
}
```

*App.js*

```
import data from 'first.js'
```

**UPD**
В вашем случае, переменная `data` находится в области видимости функции `first` и не доступна извне

```
let data = {}; // теперь доступная во всем модуле
let first = (obj) => {
  data.first = obj.foo;
  data.second = obj.bar;
}
first ({"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
export default data;
```

Comment: Все так и делал (export default data). Пишет, что data is not defined

Comment: @Александр, добавьте в вопрос ваш кода (first.js и App,js), иначе сложно о чем-то говорить

Comment: Спасибо, добавил

Comment: @Александр, обновил

Comment: Большое спасибо!